# VBA - How to copy the data from workbook to masterfile in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Good Day!Please help me on this..

1. I want to copy the data from these columns ID Code,Name,Store,Product Code,
   Brand,Form,Days,Category and Sales Using VBA
   [image: RawData]
2. Paste these values to "Master file"(template) to their desired column.
   [image: Master File Template]

Please help me I am new to VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in ThisWorkbook, modify path and filename and it should do, what you wanted. It will take ALL dataset of the first file. To modify the range of data you you could link the var "FirstDataSet" to a cell and it will start from there or save the last row it copied. This Question was asked and answered like hundreds of time on this site.

```
Public Sub Data()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim sht, msht As Worksheet
Dim lRowFile, lRowMaster As Long
Dim FirstDataSet As Integer

On Error Resume Next

Path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Files\"
Filename = "1.xlsx"

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)

    Set sht = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(1) 'First Sheet in File
    Set msht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'First Sheet in Master

    lRF = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row in File
    lRM = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row in Master
    FirstDataSet = 2 'First Data Set in File

    For i = FirstDataSet To lRF
        lRM = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row in Master
        msht.Range("B" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("A" & i).Value 'ID
        msht.Range("C" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("B" & i).Value 'Name
        msht.Range("E" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("C" & i).Value 'Store
        msht.Range("F" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("D" & i).Value 'Product Code
        msht.Range("I" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("F" & i).Value 'Brand
        msht.Range("J" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("G" & i).Value 'Form
        msht.Range("K" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("H" & i).Value 'Days
        msht.Range("L" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("I" & i).Value 'Category
        'msht.Range("M" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("K" & i).Value 'Sales
    Next i
    'This
    sht.Range("K2:AV" & lrF).Copy _ 
    Destination:= msht.Range("K2")
    wbk.Close True
End Sub
```

Comment: @UGP..Thank you for your help!

Comment: I already tried your code above. The problem I encountered is that  1. In my data source file, it only copied the A5:K5 row 2. The data was pasted on B2 in my "Master File".. :(

Comment: So it should paste all data sets into the master file now. I dont see the error with B2, in your example its the same. You can adjust where the data is put in by editing the line in the for loop. there is a comment for the name of the column

Comment: @UGP..Sorry..The data was pasted on B12..can you pls. help me?

Comment: i assume you already have data in the sheet in the rows 2 to 11 right? this macro does not overwrite values.

Comment: @UGP...None sir..I just want to paste the value from the row 2 to 11...

Comment: @ UGP..This is great Sir! I have a minor problem I tried to check it one by one. When I tried to run this msht.Range("H" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("K" & i).Value 'Days, the data pasted was not the days but sales and it was pasted in Column H..

Comment: oh you're right, fixed it. had the wrong order to take and put in.

Comment: @ UGP..Thank you again sir!..I tried to run your code but the "Brand and Category" has no data...Thank you again sir for your help..

Comment: I was not very concentrated when i did this as it seems. i switched up the colums between the two sheets. Category should have values now. I dont know why brand has none, that should work. You just have to adjust the column letters in the for loop to make it work.

Comment: @UGP..THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR!!!You are really a great help to me!!Hope there is also some one like you here in this world!!!!! Thank you and have a BLESSED DAY Sir!!!! :)

Comment: @UGP..Last question sir..What if I add another columns from my source file let say monthly report which will start on 1/1/2016 up to 1/1/2017?How will I copy that data until the last row? I tried to edit this from code `msht.Range("M" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("K" & i).Value 'Sales` to `msht.Range("M" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("K:AV" & i).Value 'Sales to monthly` report but I'm not getting any data...

Comment: I added the line to copy everything from K to AV under the for loop.

Comment: Oh Thank you again! You really helped me a lot Sir!!

Comment: @UGP..Have a bit problem sir...The value for my monthly report was pasted to "Category" column..Thank you again sir